# Filter list by date value

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, java-8, spring-data

I have a Date attribut(`date1`) in the entity(object), and i want to show a `list<object>` who is filtring by date when ( date1 < next 15 days )   like :
 (today+15days> date1>today).

Im using Jpa repository,springData on springBoot and primefaces 6,2
 Thank you

Comment: Say what again ?

Comment: So, compute the bounds and call a repository method taking these bounds as argument, and annotated with `@Query`, with the appropriate JPQL query. You need to at least try something.

Comment: @JBNizet im using Springdata , the  query jpa is like (findByAttribut)

Comment: You have an "entity(object)", then you want to have a list. Where should this list come from?

Comment: @Christine i didnt understand what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead,

Now, your repository should look like this,

```
interface YourEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, String> {

    List<YourEntity> findByDateBetween(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);

}
```

Now you can filter,

```
List<YourEntity> entities = repository.findByDateBetween(date1, date1.plusDays(15));
```

Using [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) you can *PLUS* date with different date and time fields.